# SQL: Create Triggers Instead of Unique Constraints

Tags: sql

I ma new to SQL and I am trying to make a small database with some integrity constraints. I have a database with the required constraints listed as follows

```
Movies(title, year, length, genre, studioName, producerC#)
Producer(name, address, cert#, netWorth, firmId)
Firm(id, name, address)

Movie is identified by its title
A movie may have at most one producer
No two movies can have the same title
A producer works for one and only one firm
```

I have the first one, for which I have done

```
ALTER TABLE Movies ADD PRIMARY KEY (title);
```

The second one has me slightly confused. I initially tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE Movies
    ADD CONSTRAINT uqProducer UNIQUE(title, producerC#);
```

This one works, but for some reason it still inserts the record. If I try to insert two movies of the same name with 1 producer, it spits out an error (or exception), but it still inserts the record anyway! I have done some research and it seems that I should be using triggers instead of just adding a constraint, but I'm not quite clear what the difference is or how to make a trigger that does what I need it to do here. I feel like I will need this for the other two constraints as well.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A move has by table design at most one producer. Or how would you add another one? Just refer to the producer table. No unique constraint. Just a normal foreign key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

> A movie may have at most one producer

For this rule your table structure already handles it. A movie has a FK relationship to the Producer and can only have a single producer.

Try and avoid triggers, they have their place but IMHO a last resort

Comment: Interesting. What should I use for the last two constraints?